# Why is my ArrayList being populated with duplicate node values?

Tags: java, arraylist

It should simply be 5=[6] for node 5, why 3 different values. Also, I know, this current code is buggy big time, because it would even do 2=[3,3] when I add in edges like 2,1 and 2,3. It just keeps replacing the old values with the last one and duplicates it. Here's an image with the results.

**Graph.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class Graph {

    HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adj =new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

    public void addEdge(int source, int destination) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        adj.put(source,list);
        list.add(destination);

        for(Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry: adj.entrySet()) {
            int existing = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("Existing: "+existing);
            System.out.println("Source: " +source);
            if (source != existing) {
                //adj.get(2).add(9);
                //System.out.println(source +": "+ destination);
                adj.get(source).add(destination); 

            }

        }


    }


    public void print() {
        System.out.println(adj);
    }


}
```

**AdjacencyList.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class AdjacencyList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter nodes below like (u,v):");

        Graph g = new Graph();

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)  {

            String nodes = in.nextLine();
            String[] data = nodes.split(",");

            String u    = data[0]; 
            String v    = data[1];
            int inNode  = Integer.parseInt(u);
            int outNode =Integer.parseInt(v);

            g.addEdge(inNode,outNode);
            System.out.println("Added to list");

        }


          g.print();

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) What are you even trying to do? 2) Please take your time and make use of the markup and do not post screenshots which can hardly be read.

Comment: Sorry, tried my best to figure out what you mean and what you are trying to do, but after 5 mins, I still can't figure out. Try rephrase the question to be clearer a little?

Comment: the line in your loop `adj.get(source).add(destination)` is called on _every iteration_. Obviously, by the general `Map` contract, `source != destination` must be true for at least all but one iteration. The rest of the time you repeatedly add the `destination` to the `source` list. I suspect what you _meant_ to do is `entry.getValue().add(destination)`.

Comment: Why is my ArrayList being populated with duplicate values? How hard is that to understand. Clearly, not rocket science. Anyway, I am trying to create an Adjacency list in Java and I am half way there, only to have been bugged by problem of duplicate node values being entered into my ArrayList for a node. @BoristheSpider: Correct, how do I fix that.

Comment: @OP, no need to get antsy, we're just trying to help. We cannot reproduce your issue without putting the code into our IDEs. We cannot do that with a screenshot. We cannot help you solve the problem without knowing what you're trying to achieve, we can only diagnose it - as two comments have done already.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Coded added properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you have a `Map` of `source -> List<destination>` which you are updating.

You add a new `source` node and you map it to all the existing `sources` as a `destination`.

So, for example I have

```
1 -> [2,3]
2 -> [1,3]
3 -> [1,2]
```

If I add a new mapping by calling `addEdge(4, 5)` I should end up with

```
1 -> [2,3,5]
2 -> [1,3,5]
3 -> [1,2,5]
4 -> [5]
```

Is that correct?

In this case your code is flawed. First note that here:

```
adj.get(source).add(destination);
```

You *always* add the `destination` to the `List<destination>` belonging to the source node. So when you call `addEdge(4, 5)` in the above example (assuming iteration in order for simplicity):

1. `entry.key()` is `1`, `1 != 4`, add `5` to `adj.get(4)`
2. `entry.key()` is `2`, `2 != 4`, add `5` to `adj.get(4)`
3. `entry.key()` is `3`, `3 != 4`, add `5` to `adj.get(4)`
4. `entry.key()` is `4`, `4 == 4`, noop.

So you end up with:

```
1 -> [2,3]
2 -> [1,3]
3 -> [1,2]
4 -> [5,5,5]
```

To fix this I would need to know what you expected output is for a given initial state and inputs - i.e. I would need to *algorithm*. At a guess I would say you want to do this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();

public void addEdge(int source, int destination) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    adj.put(source, list);
    list.add(destination);
    for (final Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : adj.entrySet()) {
        if (source != entry.getKey()) {
            entry.getValue().add(destination);
        }
    }
}
```

i.e.

1. `entry.key()` is `1`, `1 != 4`, add `5` to `adj.get(1)`
2. `entry.key()` is `2`, `2 != 4`, add `5` to `adj.get(2)`
3. `entry.key()` is `3`, `3 != 4`, add `5` to `adj.get(3)`
4. `entry.key()` is `4`, `4 == 4`, noop.

I have also changed the code to *program to the `interface`* and use Java 7 diamond syntax for readability.

In this case, the only reason that you need to do the check at all is that you `put` the `destination` into the new `List` you create before you loop. May I suggest:

```
public void addEdge(int source, int destination) {
    if (adj.get(source) == null) {
        adj.put(source, new ArrayList<>());

    }
    for (final Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : adj.entrySet()) {
        entry.getValue().add(destination);
    }
}
```

i.e. we check whether the mapping for the `source` is `null` and if it is we add a `new ArrayList` to `adj`. We then loop over *all* mappings and add the destination to every one of them. The outcome would be the same as above.

Here is some output from the new code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(adj);
    addEdge(1, 2);
    System.out.println(adj);
    addEdge(3, 7);
    System.out.println(adj);
    addEdge(4, 2);        
    System.out.println(adj);
}
```

Output:

```
{}
{1=[2]}
{1=[2, 7], 3=[7]}
{1=[2, 7, 2], 3=[7, 2], 4=[2]}
```

So there might be another bug - i.e. if I put the same destination in twice I get a duplicate this way. If that is not what you want a small change is required:

```
Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();

public void addEdge(int source, int destination) {
    if (adj.get(source) == null) {
        adj.put(source, new LinkedHashSet<>());

    }
    for (final Entry<Integer, Collection<Integer>> entry : adj.entrySet()) {
        entry.getValue().add(destination);
    }
}
```

Change the `Map` to hold a general `Collection` and add a `LinkedHashSet` rather than an `ArrayList`. A `LinkedHashSet` maintains order (`Linked`) and does not permit duplicate elements (`Set`).

The output would now be:

```
{}
{1=[2]}
{1=[2, 7], 3=[7]}
{1=[2, 7], 3=[7, 2], 4=[2]}
```

**EDIT**

Further to the OPs comment

*Enter nodes below like (u,v): 2,1 Added to list 2,3 Added to list 5,6 Added to list {2=[3, 6], 5=[6]}*

It seems this is simpler. The OP is wanting to maintain a simple mapping - and only update the relevant `source -> destination` and not allow duplicate destinations. The code for that is:

```
Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();

public void addEdge(int source, int destination) {
    //see if adj contains source already
    Collection<Integer> destinations = adj.get(source);
    //if not add in a new LinkedHashSet
    if (destinations == null) {
        destinations = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        adj.put(source, destinations);
    }
    //Set returns false if item exists
    if (!destinations.add(destination)) {
        System.out.println("This mapping already exists.");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{}
{1=[2]}
{1=[2], 3=[7]}
{1=[2], 3=[7], 4=[2]}
{1=[2], 3=[7], 4=[2, 3]}
This mapping already exists.
{1=[2], 3=[7], 4=[2, 3]}
```

Comment: There's a slight bug in your current code as I tested and it gives me this. Yes, there's an improvement but a thing is missing. It should give me 2=[1,3] and not 2=[3,6]. 6 belongs to 5.

Enter nodes below like (u,v):
2,1
Added to list
2,3
Added to list
5,6
Added to list
{2=[3, 6], 5=[6]}

Comment: @AliGajani corrected - from your original code I understood that you wanted to add the new `destination` once to all existing `source` nodes.

Comment: Sweet. It makes a lot of sense now. Yes, I wanted to add the destination once. If destination already exists, we just update the edges without creating it again. Also, why did you remove the for each loop though?

Comment: @AliGajani from your description I don't think it's required - if I add a new mapping `3 -> 4` I _only_ need to get the existing destinations for `3` and add `4`. I don't need to loop and check other sources.

Comment: Sure, I am trying to get my code altered to get it working. I am sure it can be done without using Java 1.7 though, even though your code is fab. I was looking for a modification to my existing code. I am of the idea that the looping you mentioned was unnecessary w.r.t checking for each mapping was horrendous on my part.

Comment: @AliGajani if you're using Java 6 you just need to copy the generic declarations across to the other side too - so `Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<Integer, Collection<Integer>>();` etc.

Comment: Thanks Boris. I hope to use Sets for eliminating duplicate values. I was just feeling a List is always a good idea but not so, because Sets do the trick. I dont think there's any performance gain from using a Set? Also, I think this is almost better than having used an Arrays of ArrayLists?

Comment: @AliGajani A `Set` will be faster in this instance as `add` is guaranteed `O(1)`. For a `List` you would need to do a `contains` operation to check for dups - this would be `O(n)`. The advantage of a `List` is access by `index` - a `Set` does not have an index so all you can do is `add` and loop over elements.